# Google Sheets: Range Not Found

Tags: google-sheets

I am new with Google Sheets scripts and I can't seem to figure why I am getting this error: Range not found (line 4, file "Code"). I have followed everything from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#creating_a_custom_function

Here is my code:

```
function getBgColor(input) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange(input);
  return range.getBackground();
}
```

I appreciate all the assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be fine if your input range is only one cell, at least if you pass it in as a string. =getBgColor("D1").
However, if you want to pass in a range, I think you will have to loop to that range in order to get the colors of the whole range. So you'll need something like this (untested):

```
function getBgColor(input) {
var bgs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(input).getBackgrounds(),
colors = [];
for(var i = 0; i < bgs.length; i++){
colors.push(bgs[i]);
}
return colors;
}
```

That should give you a range with all the backgroundcolors of the range that you passed it. If you would want those colors in one cell, use: return colors.join(", "). If you want to return only unique colors, there are also ways to do that..

See if this helps first ?

Comment: I tried the code and I got the same error. But it worked when I specified a range like .getRange("A1:B2") I wanted to use the function in a condition like =if(getBgColor("A1")="#ffff00"","Y","N")

Comment: You can build the if-statemenet right in the script so that it ouputs 'Y' or 'N' instead of the actual color.